# Gatling - How to Convert a Session-Captured String to Double and then Perform Comparison

Tags: scala, gatling

I need to be able to capture a string from the response, convert it to a double, then check whether the value is within a range. If it falls outside of the range, I want to fail the simulation.

I'm calculating CPU% time from Prometheus and have been able to extract the value from the response. What I want to do is make sure it is < a value and fail if it is. Below is what I've done so far. I've put in a println statement for the time being so that I can see if the logic is working - but so far it isn't.

CPU is collected OK, but even when it falls outside of the range, it doesn't trigger the println statement. I'm a newbie, so words of single syllables would be appreciated :-).

```
def getCalculatedCpuPercent(namespace: String, container: String) = scenario("get calculated prometheus CPU percent")
  .exec(http("get calculated prometheus CPU percent")
    .get(s"/api/v1/query")
    .queryParam("query", s"((sum by (pod_name)(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace=~'$namespace',container_name=~'$container',pod_name=~'.*'} - container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace=~'$namespace',container_name=~'$container',pod_name=~'.*'} offset 30s)) / 30) * 100")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .check(status.is(HttpStatus.SC_OK))
    .check(bodyString
      .saveAs("sBodyString"))
    .check(jsonPath("$..value[1]")
      .saveAs("metricValue"))
  )
  .exec(session => {
    val sCpuValue = ( session( "metricValue" ).as[String] )
    val cpuValue: Double = sCpuValue.toDouble
    doIf(cpuValue > 0) {
      exec { session =>
        println(session("sBodyString").as[String])
        session
      }
  }
  session})
  .exec { session =>
    println( session( "metricValue" ).as[String] )
    session}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare it with 0.0 as it is a double value:

```
doIf(cpuValue > 0.0) {
```

Comment: Sorry for the VERY slow response. Many thanks for this. :-)